# vendor javascript files missing from rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails v4.2.4.  I have tried creating a test app using the command

```
rails new app
```

Even though I can see the jquery references in the Gemfile (also present in application.js), and I have ran bundle install as well, however, the vendor/assets/javascript directoy is empty and does not include the JS files. I have already ran bundle install as well.  Am I supposed to add them by hand or did I miss a command to pull those files for me in the Rails project?

**application.js file in app/assets/javascripts**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: How do you expect the **JS** files to present in `vendor/assets/javascripts` directoy? Check in `app/assets/javascripts` directory

Comment: that directory has an application.js which refers to jquery. My question is: do I need to run a command to pull those files into the project or should they be added when I call rails new app?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.js` is inside `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory of [respective gem](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts). `jquery-rails` is a so called [Rails Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), which is a "mini-app" by itself.

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide functionality to their host applications. A Rails application is actually just a "supercharged" engine, with the Rails::Application class inheriting a lot of its behavior from Rails::Engine.

**How to find `jquery-rails` home dir**

Issue command (to find out where `jquery-rails` is located):

```
gem which jquery-rails
#=> /home/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.5/lib/jquery-rails.rb
```

`jquery-rails`'s home dir, based on output, is:

```
/home/dimitri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.5
```

Your versions and path may be different.

Comment: that's my question - the files are not there in vendor/assets/javascripts.  The application.js file in the app/assets/javascript refers to jquery etc. Do I need to run a different command to add them to the project?  Does rails new app not take care of it?

Comment: They are not in your app's directory. They are in `jquery-rails`'s home dir. See how to find `jquery-rails` home dir in updated answer.

Comment: so should I just copy/paste from there?  there is no script I can call to ensure that the dependency is added to my project? thank you for answering

Comment: @user3813256 no you don't need to. jQuery will be included into you app automatically. You can think it's already plugged in.

Comment: its not happening which is why I posted the question.  When I launch the test page in the browser, I can see missing references.

Comment: what files do you have in `app/assets/javascripts` directory?

Comment: I can see the x.x.x.x/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1 missing references in the browser dev tools window

Comment: just the application.js file.

Comment: I can copy paste the jquery and jquery_ujs files to the app/assets/javascripts irectory if that will solve the issue

Comment: once again, I am using rails v4.2.4

Comment: I know, and hence I am trying to ask here.  This is what I did: rails new testapp, I had the application.js file in the project but no jquery files.  I ran bundle install as well.

Comment: once again - my first question is this, if I run rails new app, should it not add the jquery files in the project?  please share this first,thanks

Comment: so how does one add them to the project - what's the step for it thanks

Comment: You don't need any step. In `application.js` you should have line `//= require jquery` which adds jquery for you.

Comment: its not doing it which is why I am here.  I will add application.js to my post

Comment: @user3813256 you keep speaking the same. You should listen to get answer. Either let's discuss it in chat, or share your code.

Comment: my question (and I apprecciate the feedback) is this -> what are the steps to add jquery (can you please list them out).  I have mentioned the steps I have taken.  much appreciated